# connect PickerView to a button

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have two View Controllers in my app and what I'm trying to do is that taking the pickerview data to 'CallCamp' button, then calling a different number for each selected row (only three rows)

note: the pickerview and button are in different ViewControllers.

so here what I had so far, I don't think the syntax is correct but here it is:

```
  @IBAction func CallComp(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let PickerRows = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstViewController") as? firstViewController




    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)

    { let r1 = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent:0)
        let r2 = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)
        let r3 = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 2)
        var rows = [r1,r2,r3]

        if r1 == true {if let phoneCallURL:NSURL = NSURL(string: "tel://\(900)") {
            let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.shared
            if (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL as URL)) {
                application.openURL(phoneCallURL as URL);
            }
            }
        }


        if r2 == true {if let phoneCallURL:NSURL = NSURL(string: "tel://\(909)") {
            let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.shared
            if (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL as URL)) {
                application.openURL(phoneCallURL as URL);
            }
            }
        }


      else  if r3 == true {if let phoneCallURL:NSURL = NSURL(string: "tel://\(999)") {
            let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.shared
            if (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL as URL)) {
                application.openURL(phoneCallURL as URL);
            }
            }
        }}
```

there is many errors in the code but I hope that you understand what I need

Comment: I can't say what your `switch` is supposed to do

Comment: if he/she clicks on any picker then that case should be executed. But it is implemented totally wrong

Comment: The argument to your switch is somewhat constant, it will always contain r1, r2 and r3, what is that supposed to do?

Comment: Tip: `switch row { ... }` is what you want

Comment: @Sulthan I edit the Question now, please check.

Comment: @luk2302 check the question after editing.

Answer (score -1):

`rows` is defined as an array of `Int`, and your switch cases are `Int`

You're not actually doing anything based on the pickerView selection - have you tried working through some pickerView tutorials?

Comment: I did, but it seems that the switch isn't the way to do the task here.

Comment: I think you're right - but none of us are very clear about what you're tryouts g to achieve!  Maybe show a screenshot of your pickerView and describe what you need to happen?

Comment: shall I ask a new question? or here in comments.